# time.Sleep and server-sent-events in Go - unexpected behavior

Tags: go, server-sent-events

I am trying to learn to use server sent events (SSE) with Go. The
following is the behavior that I do not understand.

**What I expect (and want to implement):** one message will be sent after every second;
this will happen five times, and then the connection will be closed.

**What actually happens**: the server waits for about 5 seconds and then sends
all messages at once and then the connection is closed.

Would appreciate if you can help me understand why this is happening.
It is not clear to me where I am going wrong with how I am thinking about this.
Every time the loop starts, it should send a message, sleep and then start a new
iteration.

Thank you.

**Relevant code on server**

```
func realTimeHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/event-stream")
    w.Header().Set("Cache-Control", "no-cache")

    i := 0
    var msg string
    for {
        msg = fmt.Sprintf("data: Message %d\n\n", i)
        i = i + 1
        w.Write([]byte(msg))
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
        if i > 5 {
            break
        }
    }
    w.Write([]byte("data:close\n\n"))
    return
}
```

**Code on client**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>SSE</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="realtime"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var evtsrc = new EventSource("/realTimeEvts");

        evtsrc.onmessage = function(e) {
            console.log("message received");
            if (e.data == "close") {
                console.log("closing connection!");
                evtsrc.close();
            }
            console.log(e.data);
        };

        evtsrc.onerror = function(e) {
            console.log(evtsrc.readyState);
            console.log("error!");
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server buffers the response body. [Flush](https://godoc.org/net/http#Flusher) the buffer to fix this issue:

```
w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/event-stream")
w.Header().Set("Cache-Control", "no-cache")
f, ok := w.(http.Flusher)
if !ok {
    http.Error(w, "sse not supported", 400)
    return
}
for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "data: Message %d\n\n", i)
    f.Flush()
    time.Sleep(time.Second)
}
w.Write([]byte("data:close\n\n"))
```

Comment: Thanks! Works great! A quick question. How did you know that it returns `ok`. That is not obvious from the documentation to me. I am new to golang and hence the question. Thanks!

Comment: `f, ok := w.(http.Flusher)` is a [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions). The the second value yielded from the assertion is a boolean indicating whether the assertion holds.